# Laravel routing - Variables show only curly braces

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I will try to be as descriptive as possible, as I haven't seen this specific problem anywhere on the Internet.

I have been unsuccessful in getting routing to work on this server without use of the public folder. Only /public/index.php is capable of displaying any sort of content, and it has been static for me.

On the tutorial I was going through (http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) he was easily able to use his code to get variables to display. When I look at my live site, I end up with static data that looks like this:

```
{{ $value->id }}    {{ $value->name }}  {{ $value->email }} {{ $value->nerd_level }}
```

[image: all the nerds]

All of my files are the exact same as his. My app/config/database.php also has proper credentials.

Apple Server 10.9.4; PHP 5.4.24; Laravel 4.2.8; mysql 5.6.20;

Comment: Is this in your view and what is your view name ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Thanks for your response. Yes, this is inside of my app/views/nerds/ folder, saved as index.blade.php

Comment: https://github.com/scotch-io/simple-laravel-crud, the difference is in my config/database.php file with proper database credentials.